# Javascript regexp take strings between {{}} but excluse those wrapped in <span>

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'd like to use a regexp to wrap all the strings between `{{ }}` but not those between `<span class="myclass">{{ }}</span>`.

I think I need to excluse `<span class="myclass">{{ }}</span>` but when I try using this :

```
text = text.replace(/(!\<span class=\"myclass\"\>.*?<\/span>)|(\{\{.*?\}\})/g, '<span class="myclass">$1</span>');
```

it also takes `<span class="myclass">{{ }}</span>` elements.
What am I doing wrong ?

Text example :

```
<span class="myclass">{{$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$}}</span>

<p>{{$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$}}</p>

<p>{{any text}}</p>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `text`'s content?

Comment: z̡a̢̖͉̝̟l̲̘̙͈̲̥͔g̖̫̖̝̀o͈̖

Comment: I updated my post with some precisions :)

Comment: Match span tags but only match and capture the other `{{...}}`s. Best way is parse the HTML with DOM and grab all `{{...}}` that are not inside span tags.

Comment: Don't use regexp for this. Instead, walk the DOM. Skip over the `span` elements you want to skip. Find text elements with `{{}}`, wrap them in a span, create a DOM element, and replace the text element with it. You might get some clues from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001242/regex-word-boundary-for-only-whitespace/36002323#36002323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of your regex (after the pipe) `(\{\{.*?\}\})` match everything between {{}}, no matter if it's between a span or not. You need to wrap it between a non matching span regex condition.

The regex must me `/^(?!<span class=\"myclass\"\>).*(\{\{.*?\}\}).*(?!<\/span>)$/g`:

- `(\{\{.*?\}\})` will select everything between {{}}, but it's encapsulated between a negative lookahead for the span that does the job

You can test it here : https://regex101.com/r/rY2cS4/5